# How do I merge two tables with different granularities? Using PySpark or SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say there are two tables and the lowest level of granularity of both is `Product#`, but there can be multiple product numbers belonging to different customers. There are targets set for each product number, but not for each ID. How do I merge Targets onto Table 1 without creating duplicates?

Table 1

| Year | customer | ID | Business# | Product# | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | abc | abc123 | 19 | 19_1 | 200 |
| 2021 | abd | abd123 | 20 | 20_2 | 500 |
| 2022 | abb | abb123 | 21 | 21_5 | 700 |
| 2020 | abt | abt123 | 22 | 22_8 | 200 |

Table 2

| Year | customer | Business# | Product# | Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | abc | 19 | 19_1 | 500 |
| 2021 | abd | 20 | 20_2 | 700 |
| 2022 | abb | 21 | 21_5 | 600 |
| 2020 | abt | 22 | 22_8 | 100 |

What I initially tried was left joining Table 1 and Table 2, which would give me duplicates of Target onto Table 3. Then I created a separate column called `ID_Count` which would count the occurrences of `ID`. Then I would create an additional column that would be called `Target_final` that would be something like `SUM(Target)/COUNT(ID_Count)`.

But I couldn't get the `Target_final` to match for some reason.

Comment: Can you provide an example with duplicates so that we understand the problem?

Comment: Because with this example, `table1.join(table_2, ['Year', 'customer', 'Business#', 'Product#'])` seems to do the trick.